# error in while statement - function containing while are not expanded inline

Tags: c++

I have a CPP (c++) program and when i am compiling it is giving ma error...

Error :   **Function containing while are not expanded inline**.
what could be the problem in while statement ?

these are the headers file which i am using.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iomanip.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<fstream.h>




 void query(long unsigned int en)
{
  int found=0;
  ifstream infile("student.dat");
  /* read the record */

  while(infile.read((char *)this,sizeof(student)))
{
  if(e_no==en)
  {
  found=1;
  query_list();
  gotoxy(26,4);
  cout<<"Query Output";
  gotoxy(35,7);
  cout<<e_no;
  gotoxy(35,8);
  cout<<name;
  fflush(stdin);
  getch();
}
  }//end of while
if(!found){clrscr();
  cout<<"Enrolment No. not found";
  getch();}
  infile.close();
}//end of query
```

Comment: Not the immediate problem, but note that you should never call `fflush(stdin)` (and especially not mixed with C++ I/O).

Comment: same error if i don't call fflush(stdin)

Comment: Is this function defined in a header file? Is it explicitly declared `inline`? If so, try moving it to the CPP file. Also it would be useful to know which compiler you are using.

Comment: That seems odd... Are you sure it's an **error** and not a **warning**? What compiler is giving this error? Also, good grief, can you mix I/O primitives a little more?

Comment: this is warning not error.. and my code is not running..

Comment: Also, I'm almost afraid to ask...  why on earth are you casting `this` to a `char*` and reading into it? This will *almost certainly* wrong and will make your program misbehave, if not outright crash.

Comment: Don't use `<iostream.h>`, use `<iostream>`. They're not the same thing.

Comment: @PraveenAnand Have you defined it within the class?? Compilers like Turbo C++ consider fucntion definition within the class as inline. Inline functions are replaced at the place of call. Functions with while loops are not considered inline by some compilers. You need to define it outside the class with a scope resolution operator. And incase you code is not working (that is after this warning is removed) update your code to reflect the error or issue.

Comment: Try using a compiler from the current millenium. `<iostream.h>` hasn't been legal for a long time. And secondly, consider posting a complete example- your function clearly cannot compile since it uses `this` but is not a member.

Comment: @PraveenAnand If your office/college insists on using the same compiler (which doesnt use `#include<iostream>`but the `.h` version) I suggest you practise with some other modern compiler too. You know just to keep urself updated

Answer (score 2):

One reason your program doesn't run is because you likely destroy or corrupt what `this` points to by casting it to a `char*` and then reading data into it. This is almost certainly wrong and not what you want to do.

Also, please use C++ style includes. `<iostream.h>` went the way of the dodo before the dodo did. And don't `fflush` the `stdin` handle or mix C and C++ style IO.

Comment: While it's not usual to cast `this` to `char*` and read into it, but this can actually be perfectly valid, if an odd way of reading in data. There are preconditions, such as `this` being an object of class `student`, class `student` not being virtual (ie, having no v-table), containing only POD-types and no pointers, and of course that the file itself contains only records of `student`. Agreed it is _an odd way to do it_, but following those preconditions it should not destroy or corrupt anything.

Comment: I agree it *could* possibly be ok (if ugly), but this sort of thing should be discouraged - or at the very least not be encouraged. Considering that we have a small snippet of code to go from in determining why this program doesn't work (and an irrelevant "error" that was then was magically turned into a warning) I think targeting the elephant in the room is sensible.

Comment: Indeed, I don't disagree with that - changing to a more standard way of reading in the data would help eliminate possible avenues of error.